# public inheritance of std::fstream and overloading operator<< for char* not actually writing to the Output file

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class SychronizedFileWriter : public std::fstream {
  //std::mutex _mutex;

public:
  SychronizedFileWriter(std::string&& filePath);
  virtual ~SychronizedFileWriter();

  bool is_open() const;
  // SychronizedFileWriter& operator<<(const char* s);
  // SychronizedFileWriter& operator<<(SychronizedFileWriter& sfw, const signed char* s);
  // SychronizedFileWriter& operator<<(SychronizedFileWriter& sfw, const unsigned char* s);

};

SychronizedFileWriter::SychronizedFileWriter(std::string&& filePath)
{
  std::fstream::open(filePath, std::ios_base::app);
}

SychronizedFileWriter:: ~SychronizedFileWriter()
{
  std::fstream::close();
}

bool
SychronizedFileWriter::is_open() const
{
  return std::fstream::is_open();
}

template<typename T, typename S>
T& operator<<(T& fs, const S* s)
{
  std::cout << "im here\n";
  {
    // Take mutex lock 

    fs.std::fstream::operator<<(s);
   }
  return fs;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(true);

  SychronizedFileWriter sfw(std::string("./test.txt"));

  std::cout << "open: " << std::boolalpha << sfw.is_open();

  sfw << "Hello, Worked!!!!" << "\n";

  exit(0);
}
```

Code compiled successfully. However, "text.txt" does not contain the string "Hello, Worked!!!!" but it is empty. My purpose is just to use this class as a wrapper to operator<< so that i can use mutex to synchronize writing to the same file by different threads.
Thanks in Advance and highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Does the program print out "i'm here"?

Comment: Yes, it prints that. `]# ./a.out
open: true
Im here
Im here
`

Comment: `operator<<` for `const char*` is a free function, not a member of `std::fstream`. I'm not sure exactly what overload your code ends up calling, but it's not the one you expect.